# How can I use different sizes of training data and test data and different batch_sizes during fitting and predicting data using Keras LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

My source code looks in the way shown below. It works only when batch_sizes have the same size, in this case `300` and the same shape, in this case `(300, 50, 74)`. Does anyone have an idea how can I use different sizes of training data and test data and different batch_sizes during fitting and predicting data using Keras LSTM?

```
shape = input_one_hot_encoded.shape
print('input_one_hot_encoded: ' + str(shape))

shape = output_one_hot_encoded.shape
print('output_one_hot_encoded: ' + str(shape))

shape = test_input_one_hot_encoded.shape
print('test_input_one_hot_encoded: ' + str(shape))


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(len(dict), return_sequences=True, stateful=True,
               batch_input_shape=shape))
model.add(LSTM(len(dict), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(LSTM(len(dict), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(len(dict), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

model.fit(input_one_hot_encoded, output_one_hot_encoded, epochs=20, batch_size=300)

data = model.predict(test_input_one_hot_encoded, batch_size=300)
```

It returns:

```
input_one_hot_encoded: (300, 50, 74)
output_one_hot_encoded: (300, 50, 74)
test_input_one_hot_encoded: (300, 50, 74)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (300, 50, 74)             44104     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (300, 50, 74)             44104     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (300, 50, 74)             44104     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (300, 50, 74)             5550      
=================================================================
Total params: 137,862
Trainable params: 137,862
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't use different batch sizes while training and test run is that your model has stateful LSTM i.e. the value of stateful parameter is set to True

Now, there are two ways to solve this:

1. Use stateful LSTM while training. At the end of the training process save the weights of your model locally to a file and define a new model architecture same as the existing one with only difference that lstms are not statefule:

   ```
   model.save_weights("your_weights.h5")
   ```

   e.g. lstm layers

   ```
   model.add(LSTM(len(dict), return_sequences=True, stateful=False, batch_input_shape=shape))
   ```
2. Just make your lstm layers non-stateful i.e. set the value of stateful argument to False as above.

For more detail description please refer this link https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the docs regarding the input shape of LSTM cells:

> 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim).

Which implies that you you're going to need timesteps with a constant size for each batch, hence it wont be possible to have different batch sizes for training and testing.

However, you can change the length of your input sequence for example by using `pad_sequences` (see https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequence for more details)

Example:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
# define sequences
sequences = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
             [1]
    ]
# pad sequence
padded = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=5)
print(padded)
[[0 1 2 3 4]
[0 0 1 2 3]
[0 0 0 0 1]]
```

EDIT after comments:

you need to adjust your test-data dimensions. For example see the docs on sequential models (https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/). Here x_train and y_train are defined as follows:

```
data_dim = 16
timesteps = 8
num_classes = 10
batch_size = 32

# Generate dummy training data
x_train = np.random.random((batch_size * 10, timesteps, data_dim))
y_train = np.random.random((batch_size * 10, num_classes))
```

note that the shapes are

```
x_train.shape
>> (320, 8, 16)
y_train.shape
>> (320, 10)
```

Your shapes should read:

```
input_one_hot_encoded.shape
>> (300, timesteps, data_dim)
output_one_hot_encoded.shape
>>(300, num_classes)
```

respectively

Comment: Okay, let's assume that I have the same size for each batch however in my source code I can only use the same size as first value in shape. When I have for instance `input_one_hot_encoded: (300, 50, 74)
output_one_hot_encoded: (300, 50, 74)
test_input_one_hot_encoded: (300, 50, 74)` and in both cases `batch_size=30` I get error `model.fit(input_one_hot_encoded, output_one_hot_encoded, epochs=20, batch_size=30) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [30,50,74] vs. [300,50,74]` Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly but judging from your error argument "[30,50,74] vs. [300,50,74]" it appears that you model input is ill-defined. Did you check if you have adjusted batch_input_shape=shape to match your batch size?

Comment: In this case `len(dict)` is equals to 74. How can I change my model?

Comment: see my updated answer for an example on how to use pad_sequences. You simply need to pass the sequences inside your dict to the pad_sequence function. You can also use the maxlen parameter to define a desired output size.

Comment: But I am not sure what is the purpose of changing list size? My all lists in lists in numpy array have the same length.

Comment: I assumed that's what your asking " Does anyone have an idea how can I use different sizes of training data and test data [...]"

Comment: I'm sorry it could sound ambiguously. By the way thank you for your help. My problem is that I have pre-processed data and encoded using one hot encoding. In my numpy array I have all lists and each of them contains 50 another lists and each of them contains as many elements as contains dictionary. For instance in the example above it was 74 elements. There was used one hot encoder so each list contains 73 zeros and 1 one. At the moment I want to use this data to learn model using train data and predict data for test data. Both of them are pre-processed as I have described above.

Comment: I have `450000` train data and `35000` test data. The problem is that I can't use `450000` train data to learn model and then use `35000` test data to predict this data because when I use different input data sizes I get the errors which I shown you above. Besides I can't use for instance for this model batch size different than size of the data because I also get the errors shown above. So at the moment the only way to generate any predictions is to use in both cases `35000` train and test data and in both cases `batch_size=35000`. But as you see it doesn't look good. Is it more clear now?

Comment: So maybe there is a problem with `output_one_hot_encoded`. Because it has the same shape as `input_one_hot_encoded`, to wit `(300, 50, 74)`. But I am not sure what is the difference. Shouldn't I use one hot encoder for `output_one_hot_encoded` and create only two dimensional array with integers?

Comment: output_one_hot_encoded needs to have shape (300, num_classes) i.e be. 2D not 3D

Comment: Yes, but let's assume that I have train data and input string `hello world` and output for instance `hola mundo`. We assume that all lists will have 13 elements. So for `hello world` I do `[h,e,l,l,o, ,w,o,r,l,d,'','']` and then `[0,1,2,2,3,4,5,3,6,2,7,8,8]`. Then I use one hot encoding and get `[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] x 13...]` This will be my input data - 3 dimensional array because I can have multiple sentences which contains multiple words which I code to characters and finally encode using one hot. I did the same with the train output data. Is it wrong? What I should do?

Comment: I think your confusion arises from not being familiar with how to preprocess the input data. After tokenizing you do not need to create a one-hot represenation of every single character. just use your [0,1,2,2,3,4,5,3,6,2,7,8,8] list as an input sequence ( of length 13). Now if you want to pass in "hola mundo" which is length 10 you would use padding as described in my answer to add two zeros to the end of the list, such that it will be a sequence of 13 integers. See this tutorial for more on this topic https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-character-based-neural-language-model-keras/